# Docker Grafana with two InfluxDBs: Connection refused

Tags: docker, grafana, influxdb

i created a new docker-stack where i would need several influxdb instances, which i can’t connect to my grafana container atm. Here is a port of my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - grafana-volume:/var/lib/grafana

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    container_name: influxdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - influxdb-volume:/var/lib/influxdb

  influxdb-2:
    image: influxdb
    container_name: influxdb-2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 12380:12380
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - influxdb-volume-2:/var/lib/influxdb
```

When i try to create a new influxdb datasource in grafana with influxdb-2 i get a Network Error: Bad Gateway(502), the logfile is showing:

```
2782ca98a4d7_grafana | 2019/10/05 13:18:50 http: proxy error: dial tcp 172.20.0.4:12380: connect: connection refused
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why is `influxdb-2` exposing `12380` instead of `8086`?

Comment: Since i need power two containers. I thought i need to address them seperatly?

Comment: You do not. And if, it would be `12380:8086`, unless you changed the port influxdb is listening to in influxdb-2.

Answer (score 3):

@hmm provides the answer.

When you create services within Docker Compose, you:

- are able to access containers by the service name. Grafana will reference `influxdb-2` by that name.
- are **not** able to change the ports a container exposes. Per @hmm, `influxdb-2` must still be referenced on port `8086` because that's the port the container exposes; you can't change it unless you change the image.
- you may (but you don't need to) expose the containers' ports to the host (using `--ports: [[HOST-PORT]]:[[CONTAINER-PORT]]`

The long and the short of it is that the InfluxDB service in `influxdb-2` should be referenced as `influxdb-2:8086`. If you want to expose this service to the host (!), you could do `ports: - 12380:8086`. You may change the value of `12380` to something available on your host but you cannot change the value of the container port (`8086`).

The main reason that you would include the `--ports:` flag on `influxdb-2` is for debugging from the host. But the `grafana` service does not require this. It will access the `influxdb-2` service through the network provisioned by Docker Compose on port `8086`.

You **do** want to expose the `grafana` service on the host because, otherwise, it would be inaccessible to you (from the host). It's akin to public|private. `grafana` is host public but the `influxdb*` services may be host private because they are generally only needed by the `grafana` service.

Comment: Sorry, i posted the wrong version of the file. I am already using 12380:8086 for influxdb-2 which is giving me this error. So this isnt the solution

Comment: You cannot reference `influxdb-2` from `grafana` using `12380`. The `grafana` service knows `influxdb-2` by than name and using port `8086`. The error suggests you're incorrectly referencing `influxdb-2` by port `12380`: tcp 172.20.0.4:12380: connect: connection refused

Comment: @Ochzo Then please update the question by editing it.

Comment: Another point to note: No need to set up a network manually. A network is created automatically be docker-compose.